# Why does MSVS static analyzer ignore _Check_return_?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, static-analysis

What is the correct way to annotate a function with `_Check_return_`?
In the following example static analyzer produces only one warning instead of two:

```
_Check_return_ int foo()
{
    return 42;
}

_Check_return_ std::string bar()
{
    return std::string();
}

int main()
{
    foo(); // Return value ignored
    bar(); // No warning

    return 0;
}
```

Tested on MSVS 2015 Update 3.

Comment: Hmya, the compiler does not ignore it.  It has to call the destructor.  Try `_Must_inspect_result_`

Comment: Exactly the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you just did not turn on "Enable Code Analysis on Build" check-box in the project's configuration.